# how to add vertical lines inside the line

Tags: javafx, line, scene

Here is my code as follows:

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

    Line line = new Line(100,0,300,0);
    line.setStrokeWidth(20);
    line.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
    root.getChildren().add(line);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
 }
```

Here is the image (as it will be more clear if I show the image)

[image: Line]

My question is that: I want to design my `line`, so I want to add vertical lines inside my `line`. Is there any way I can do that? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be drawn for example by using two `Line`s:

```
public class LineDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        // Background line
        Line lineBlack = new Line(98,50,302,50);
        lineBlack.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        lineBlack.setStrokeWidth(24);
        lineBlack.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);

        // Top line
        Line line = new Line(100,50,300,50);
        line.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        line.setStrokeWidth(20);

        // Vertical lines
        line.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(20d, 2d, 40d, 2d, 82d, 2d, 20d, 2d, 30d);
        line.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);


        root.getChildren().addAll(lineBlack, line);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

To get a result like:

[image]

Note: It can be also solved completely with `LinearGradient`s.